# How to add multiple assertions in soapUI

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui

I want to add multiple assertions in soapUI, like if in response:

```
  <ns0:Message>A</ns0:Message>
```

is returned. I want to add, "A", "B", "C" as assertions, so that if any of the values is returned, the assertion could Pass. Thanks!

```
 <soapenv:Body>
  <ns0:Fault xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <faultcode>OSB-382500</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Mandatory Parameter Customer Type cannot be empty (uuid: 1f8b9637-11b1-47ea-9ebd-3abf2fda950e)</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <ns0:Fault xmlns:ns0="http://group.vodafone.com/contract/vfo/fault/v1" xmlns:ns2="http://group.vodafone.com/contract/vho/header/v1" xmlns:ns3="http://group.vodafone.com/schema/common/v1" xmlns:ns6="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" xmlns:ns7="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
           <ns6:Timestamp>2017-08-16T20:44:27.15+05:30</ns6:Timestamp>
           <ns6:ErrorCode>500</ns6:ErrorCode>
           <ns0:Name/>
           <ns0:Severity>Critical</ns0:Severity>
           <ns0:Category>Technical</ns0:Category>
           <ns0:ReasonCode>ReasonCode</ns0:ReasonCode>
           <ns0:Message>A</ns0:Message>
        </ns0:Fault>
     </detail>
  </ns0:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: You mean tag can have either A, B, C as values?

Comment: yes exactly....

Comment: Please check the answer and see if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a sample xml, since you haven't mentioned any data.

In SoapUI, you can use below `Script Assertion`:

```
assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'  

//Define or change for the assertion
def validValues = ['Tag': ['A', 'B', 'C']]
def tagToFind = 'Tag'

def pxml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)

//Find all the tag values and filter those are not in valid values
def result = pxml.'**'.findAll{it.name() == tagToFind &&  !(it.text() in validValues[tagToFind])}
assert !result, "Elements ${tagToFind} have different values other than valid- ${result}"
```

You can find the online <kbd>[demo](http://ideone.com/pOvmt4)</kbd> quickly with sample xml.

Note that, the sample xml shows assertion error as it has other values than expected.

Comment: @Abhishek, have you seen the demo and assertion error? Have you modified the above mentioned script? Would you mind showing the data you have used?

Comment: @Abhishek, all you need to do is replace `Tag` with `Message`. Give it a try.

Comment: @Rao, I tried with *.contains method. Couldnt verify regex based multiple assertions. This example is very nice. Thanks for sharing.